# Concatenate strings in Oracle SQL without a space in between?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, oracle10g, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate strings in oracle.

The following is my query:

```
insert into dummy values('c'||to_char(10000,'99999'));
```

The expected result is:

```
c10000
```

But the output I get is with a space in between 'c' and the value 10000:

```
c 10000
```

How to concat without spaces?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not an issue with the concatenation operator but with the function `to_char()`. Try instead:

```
to_char(10000,'FM99999')
```

I quote [the manual here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#autoId0):

> FM .. 
>   Returns a value with no leading or trailing blanks.

Answer (score -1):

There are two solutions:

1. Fill Mode ('`FM`') formatting prefix that suppresses the additional blank character prefix for the `to_char` number conversion. I suggest this one is preferred, because it is integrated with the to_char format and does not require an additional function call;
2. `LTRIM` of the returned value from the `to_char` number conversion.

The code below shows the results of both solutions:

```
Select concat('NTA', to_char(1,'FM0000000000000')), 
concat('NTA', ltrim(to_char(1,'0000000000000'))), 
concat('NTA', to_char(1,'0000000000000'))
from dual;
```

`"CONCAT('NTA',TO_CHAR(1,'FM0000000000000'))"`: "NTA0000000000001"
`"CONCAT('NTA',LTRIM(TO_CHAR(1,'0000000000000')))"`: "NTA0000000000001"
`"CONCAT('NTA',TO_CHAR(1,'0000000000000'))"`: "NTA 0000000000001"